# Substract 2 columns on select prevent NULL on second column witouth using IF?

Tags: mysql

In my shop i have the possibility to order products by price ascending and descending.

Now i implement sales and the problem i have products arent sort correctly anymore.

For example ASC:

1. Product 1: 10€
2. Product 2: 11€ (-2€) = 9€

On product table i have the price and on sale table i have the value of how much the product costs less (example above 2€).
So i left joined the sale table and in the SELECT statement i do `(productprice - salevalue) AS pricesort`.

THE PROBLEM:
If a product has no sale the joined value is NULL and if i subtract null from the productprice this go NULL to.

Is there any way to prevent productprice to get NULL if i subtract salevalue = NULL witouth using IF ?

(10 - NULL) = NULL   ->    (10 - NULL) = 10

Comment: @Barmar thanks exactly i searched for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `productprice - IFNULL(salevalue, 0) AS pricesort`. `IFNULL(x, y)` returns `x` if `x` not null, `y` if it is.